# Why Pointer+Pointer is not allowed but Pointer+integer allowed?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I was going through C Pointer arithmetic. I found that pointer addition is not allowed but `pointer + integer` is allowed.

I thought `pointer + pointer` is not allowed due to security reason. But what if a pointer say `p1` holds `66400` and `p2` holds `66444`. now `p1+p2` is not allowed but `p1+66444` is allowed. Why so?

Comment: Does pointer + pointer even make sense to you? What could the practical application of this possibly be? There is no application in adding the addresses of two objects in memory, while pointer + integer gives you an offset, which can indeed be useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think this way.

```
Address 1: 112, Bakers street
Address 2: 11, Nathan road
```

Why `Address1 + 3` is fine but `Address1 + Address2` is bad.

(BTW by `Address1 + 3` I mean 115, Backers street)

For the same reason multiplication of scalar or an address to another address doesn't make sense.

```
address1 * 2 // Invalid
address1 * address2 // Invalid
```

Logically it is possibly to take an offset from an address by adding/subtracting but adding 2 addresses doesn't make sense because addresses of same variables may be different in each run of program. Moreover the type and value of addition don't make any sense.

> I thought pointer + pointer is not allowed due to security reason.

No it is not allowed because addition of pointers does not make any sense.

> if a pointer say `p1` holds `66400` and `p2` holds `66444`. now
>   `p1+p2` is not allowed but `p1+66444` is allowed.

You are thinking only about values think of their types also. For example if `a` holds `2` kg, and `b` holds `3` meter, it does not make sense to add them.

---

There is one more important thing to learn from address analogy:

Let's say there are 80 houses on Nathan road (analogous to arrays in C) and if you add `70` to `Address 2` you may land in a house, a garbage bag, or in the sea. For the same reason, if you go more than 1 past the address in array or address before the  of array behaviour is undefined. If you dereference any address beyond the array, behaviour is undefined.

```
int NathanRoad[80] = {...};
int *address1 = &NathanRoad[11];
int *q;
int s;
q = address1 + 3; /* OK */
s = *(address1 + 3); /* OK */
q = address1 + 75; /* Bad */
q = address1 + 69; /* OK */
s = *(address1 + 69); /* Bad */
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you could treat pointers as integers, but you really shouldn't.

Pointer+integer means position+offset, which yields a new position. Pointer+pointer would mean position+position, which doesn't make sense.

Similarly in maths, if that helps you. While a 2D vector and a 2D coordinate can both be expressed similarly, it only makes sense to add the vectors, not the coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Just think of it logically.

If you add two pointers, what will be the result? It is most likely to make no sense.

OTOH, addition of an integer means *increment* (or decrement) the pointer location (with regards to the type of pointer). The pointer is the *location* and the *integer* is the *offset*. Logical and valid.

Technically speaking, the addition `+` operator, from `C11`, chapter §6.5.6, also mandates,

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or **one operand shall be a
>   pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is
>   equivalent to adding 1.)**

Answer (score 0):

Pointers aren't integers. Pointer arithmetic works like this: If you have a pointer `p` to an array element `a[i]` and and integer `n`, then `p + n` is a pointer to `a[i + n]`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding pointer to pointer is pointless (pun intended) it just doesn't make sense.

Adding a pointer to an integer can give a useful result. Depending on the usage of course.

Subtraction of two pointers is supported because it can be useful for estimating sizes. How many elements would fit in between?